# A question on Ahlfors covering surface

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces, complex-dynamics

Given a transcendental entire function $f$, and three Jordan domains $D_1$, $D_2$, and $D_3$ such that the closures of the three Jordan domains do not intersect with each other. Then from Ahlfors covering surface (See in Walter Hayman's book), we can choose $i\in {1,2,3}$ such that there are INFINITELY MANY univalent island over $D_i$.

I wondered whether this interesting theorem can be proved by other method? Ahlfors original proof relies on his important inequality on covering surface, which seems highly non-trivial.  Any comments and remarks will be appreciated.

Edit: In the original version of the question, I only assume three disjoint Jordan domains does not intersect with each other. In fact, this is not enough .  Professor Alexandre Eremenko pointed out in fact it should be the closures of the three domains do not intersect with each other.

Comment: You might want to give a more detailed description of what it is you seek.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you. My question is about is there a relatively basic proof to prove infinitely many univalent island argument in the statement.

Comment: I can give a heuristic and personal view on this, that I developped when I tried to understand Bloch's theorem on an intuitive level. (note: I don't know the proofs of Ahlfors' island theorems). It has to do with the difference between C (the complex plane) and D (the unit disk). The first is essentially euclidean and the second essentially hyperbolic. Before continuing, I need to know if you see what I mean by this, for otherwise I need first to develop the corresponding intuition.

Comment: @ArnaudChéritat Thank you, I know what you mean. You can continue your view towards on this.

Comment: You misstated the theorem. The CLOSURES of the domains must be disjoint.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko  Oh, I am sorry for the mistake for the statement, You are right. Thank you, professor. I re-edit my question.

Comment: @ArnaudChéritat I do not know whether your heuristic and personal view is some thing related to what is so called Bloch principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_principle

Comment: to yaoxiao : I have never heard of this principle before!

Answer (score 5):

If you read French, the article "Sur la théorie d'Ahlfors des surfaces" by Duval may be interesting: http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1589 .

It covers the full Ahlfors theory, not just the islands theorem. If you want only the latter, then Bergweiler's proof (which I think is actually very intuitive, well at least for the infinitesimal version) is probably your best bet.

Comment: Yes, Bergweiler's proof is essentially give a very interesting and explicit correspondence between traditional second Nevanlinna theorem   and Ahlfors' s version of covering surface theorem. Thanks your french article. Always, I need to guess during I read French article.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can, see the paper *A new proof of the Ahlfors five islands theorem* by Walter Bergweiler. The proof is based on a result on Nevanlinna concerning perfectly branched values, Zalcman's rescaling lemma for non-normal families and the existence of solutions to the Beltrami equation (so-called Measurable Riemann mapping theorem).

You could also take a look at Bergweiler's other paper *The role of the Ahlfors five islands theorem in complex dynamics* for interesting applications.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know this proof, which based on Zalcman theorem. Again,  this may also not a intuitive proof.

Comment: It does not matter whether the domains are disks or not. Bergweiler's proof applies to any Jordan domains with disjoint closures.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Ah yes indeed, I corrected, thanks. I was referring to the proof in the second paper.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the two papers mentioned by Malik Younsi and Lasse Rempe Gillen,
there are these two papers:

> Tôki, Yukinari, Proof of Ahlfors principal covering theorem. Rev. Math. Pures Appl. 2 1957 277–280.
>
> de Thélin, Henry, Une démonstration du théorème de recouvrement de surfaces d'Ahlfors. Enseign. Math. (2) 51 (2005), no. 3-4, 203–209,

each containing a simplified proof of Ahlfors's two fundamental theorems. (The second fundamental theorem implies the island theorem). These four proofs make a complete list, I suppose.

Comment: Dear professor, if someone only cares  this  question: for  a transcendental entire function $f$, and three Jordan domains $D_1$, $D_2$, and $D_3$  whose closures do not intersect with each other, we can choose $i\in {1,2,3}$ such that there are INFINITELY MANY univalent island over $D_i$.  Does this fact was  unknown before Ahlfors in history of complex analysis? And also besides bergweiler's proof,   did someone  prove this fact with  different machinery later?

Comment: I suppose this fact was not known before Ahlfors. Actually it was conjectured by A. Bloch. Besides Bergweiler proof, 3 other proofs were mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Now I feel shy because there are some people watching that really know what they are talking about, unlike me. So a word of warning: anything I am going to write here may be too optimistic (or stupid). It is certainly extremely vague. With that said, the point of view I refer to is: consider the domain of f as a Riemann surface over the target. By this I mean that you can reconstruct dom(f) by patching pieces of the target using f to understand how to glue things. A the level of critical point, you have to remove the critical value and add several copies of the pieces that you may have to cut. This is already idealistic since there are also asymptotic values (points whose preimage is "at infinity", more rigorously, points $a$ in the range such that there is a path in the domain tending to the boundary of dom(f) and whose image by f tends to $a$). The prototype of the latter is the point 0 in the range of f=the exponential map, where a preimage of a neighborhood of 0 is an infinite cover over a punctured disk. But it may be less nice.

Some more heuristics: the infinity of C is small, the infinity of D is big. In fact, you can recompose D by patching many copies of a single compact patch, exponentially many as you wander off to the boundary of D, if you count the distance by how many patches you need to cross. Archetypical examples:

1. the universal cover of C minus two points,
2. Ahlfors' conjectured optimal function for the Bloch constant. This will not be possible for C.

In short: D is hyperbolic, C is parabolic (this is very vague, I know; there is at least one thing that makes me uneasy about all this presentation of things: that C nevertheless contains D.).

Now, anytime you have an island, you have a patch that is a copy of the domain D$_i$. If you start from a point in the domain, mapped in D$_i$, and try to lift D$_i$ by f and hit a problem, is may be because you need to put a ramification point, so this increases the number of patches you need... kind of... in fact you will probalbyhave to cut your patch into smaller pieces, because of more ramification points: but then the heuristics is that it only improves things (it makes dom(f) more hyperbolic). If the problem is not due to a ramification point, then it there is an asymptotic value, and again this leads to many patches: in some sense, it is even more hyperbolic than just having ramification points.

If $f$ is transcendental and some D$_i$ has only finitely many islands, then close enough to the boundary of dom(f), it is a bit like there is no islands. By the discussion above other preimages will be ramified, or worse. Now if there are enough D$_i$ with this property, then the game is to see that, on a purely combinatorial level, there must at least an exponential growth of the patches (this is idealistic but this gives an idea): this is what happens with the two examples above.

Let us look at an example that works not: cos(z).
Its critical points are points of $\pi\mathbb Z$, half of which get mapped to -1 the other half to 1. There is no asymptotic value (in fact, infinity is). The number of patches (whatever that means) grows linearly with the combinatorial distance. More precisely if you take D$_1$ and D$_2$ two disks about -1 and 1, their preimages are all ramified of ramification number=2. Join them by a line. Then the preimage of this picture is many disks-like domains at all the points of $\pi\mathbb Z$ all joined to the next by a line. This graph is more "euclidean" than "hyperbolic".

Now if you have three domains D$_i$, take a point outside and link this point to each D$_i$ by disjoint curves, giving a Y-shaped picture with three disks attached at the tips. Ideally, the preimage of this graph contains (infinitely) many copies of this Y-shaped curve with disks at tips and to each of these disk (with finitely many exceptions) is attached at least two distinct copies of a Y. Such a graph is necessarily hyperbolic.

Again, I do not know the proof of Ahlfors' theorems, and I completely forgot the proof of Bloch's theorem, so all this may be far from the actual proofs. This is just my point of view on things.

Comment: Thank you, professor. It will take me some time to digest this interesting idea.